# Document_New Not Working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created Macro Enables Templates which will execute the `Document_New` sub when it opens but to have something for all word documents I can seem to get it right.

I have included the following Script into the `Normal` Project

> Microsoft Word Objects > ThisDocument

[image]

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    'When you open an Exisiting Word Document
    MsgBox "This Worked"
    Call SomeMacro
 End Sub
```

---

```
 Private Sub Document_New()
   'When you open a New Word Document with Word already Open
   MsgBox "This Worked"
   Call SomeMacro
 End Sub
```

**Note:** This will only auto run the Macro when you open a Word Document that exists already. It will not work if you open Word using the Application Button as found in the Start Menu > Programs >Microsoft Office.

I have seen people referring to Event handlers, but I am not sure what that it.

I am using Word 2010.

Want to see if there is a way for a Macro to execute if the Word.exe is run

Comment: What's your question, exactly? And which version of Word are we discussing?

Comment: @CindyMeister see my edit. Basically running a Macro when Word.Application  is initialized using the Application  shortcut from the startmenu/applications/Microsoft office/Word

Comment: What always worked quite well, as I recall, is a macro named AutoNew. Unlike one in the ThisDocument class it's not specific to the document in which it resides, but is "global". Also "global" would be the NewDocument event in a class module (not ThisDocument). This assumes, however, that a new document is created when Word is executed - but that does not need to be the case. More reliable would be a COM/VSTO Add-in with code executing when it loads.

Comment: Yes some of the discussions I have seem state the need of a Add-In. I believe that the AutoNew was removed with Word2010

Comment: No, AutoNew is still there :-) But I remember, now: the macro that runs when Word starts is AutoExec. Have you tried that one?

Comment: Will try tomorrow, where would I place that Macro? In the same place from the image above?

Comment: NOT in ThisDocument - in any "normal" module (NewMacros is a "normal" module, for example).

Comment: @CindyMeister it worked, post as an Answer and I will select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a macro that executes whenever Word starts up use the macro name: AutoExec. Be sure to place the macro in a "normal" module, not a class module or ThisDocument (which is also a kind of class module).